# Selecting bars vertically in Sibelius

Tags: notation, sibelius

I have made a layout of auto system breaks in Sibelius by every 7 bars (layout-> breaks-> auto breaks). Now I want to select bars vertically, but if I press shift key and select bars by column, it overlaps by both rows and columns. How could I make a selection of bars vertically down?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The System Passage Select command in Sibelius selects a group of bars in a score that play simultaneously, e.g. every bar 6 in every instrument in the score.

The sample you supplied shows either a single part or a score containing just one instrument. You're trying to use the System Passage Select tool to create a group of bars containing bars 6 and 13 and 20, etc., which is not a System Passage, i.e. not a vertical selection.

I think the best you can do is copy the bars individually.

Comment: The above answer seems to have been misunderstood as suggesting a method of making the sort of multiple selection asked for.  I'm afraid it doesn't.  I trust this comment is helpful!